getting data from google tabs to html page
i´m new to html and creating pages, so i need help.
i have this google form, where i put ingedience and stuff ((makeing a web for moms recepies)) and then it goes to the google sheets. i need to pull that infomations and put them on the page separating sweet recepies from salty ((it's already in the tab if it's this or that)). i will post the tab and also my html code. if someone can, please help.
((i have it in czech soo "sladké" means sweet and "slané" means salty, last column "postup" means steps for the cooking process))
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MP70bVV6hTeq-D5Jcc24_vrKXR695RZUrtsn_g-IHmE/edit?usp=sharing
main page:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cz">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Kuchařka ztracených receptů</title>
</head>
<style>
    button {
    color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
    background-color: rgb(53, 104, 139);
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15pt;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 15px; /*15px mezera z top, right, bottom, left*/
}

h1 {
    color: rgb(21, 42, 55);
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30pt;
}

.button-container {
    text-align: center; /*centrování tlačítek*/
    margin-top: 20px; /* místo nad tlačítky */
}

</style>
<body style="background-color:rgb(179, 199, 213);">
    <h1>Kuchařka ztracených receptů</h1>
    <div class="button-container">
        <a href="sladke.html"><button>Sladké</button></a>
        <a href="slane.html"><button>Slané</button></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Sladké/sweet:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cz">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sladké</title>

</head>

<style>
    button {
    color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
    background-color: rgb(42, 84, 111);
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
   
}

h3 {
    color: rgb(21, 42, 55);
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20pt;
}


</style>

<body>
    <h3>Sladké recepty</h3>
    <a href="poseruse.html"><button>Hlavní stránka</button></a>
</body>
</html>

Slané/salty
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cz">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Slané</title>
</head>

<style>
button {
    color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
    background-color: rgb(42, 84, 111);
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
  
}

h3 {
    color: rgb(21, 42, 55);
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20pt;
}

</style>

<body>
    <h3>Slané recepty</h3>
    <a href="poseruse.html"><button>Hlavní stránka</button></a>

</body>
</html>


thanks
i tried looking up, but i didnt find what i needed

Why is Can Someone Help Me not a useful question

Do you know how to use Apps Script?

makeing a web for moms recepies Are you using Google Sites, or have you created your own external website?

@LimeHusky thats the script platform from google?? i really dont but i can look on yt. you think that would help me with pulling the data from the sheets? or shoud i work in it?

@Tedinoz i created my own ((theres even the code for it)). like i know google sites would be easier, but its my project for my programming class so i dont think that would be propriet.

Yes, it's definitely Appscript @KláraSzkawranioková.

i know google sites would be easier There are pros and cons to everything; I wasn't making a value judgement just trying to clarify the environment. i created my own Then that would require a different approach than than if you had used Google Sheets. It appears that @LimeHusky has a solution. I do hope that it meets your expectations.

Web App and Importing Data in Sheets
The solution I came up with is using Web App in Apps Script. I added and modified your code.

Sample Output:
index.html

recipe.html


This is How you Setup

Open Google App Script Create New Project.
Create New Project



After Creating a Project Add another 2 html files and Name it index and recipe.




Put this in your Code.gs.



function doGet(e) {
  let html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(e.parameter.page || "index");
  let data = getValues();
  if (e.parameter.title) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i][1] == e.parameter.title) {
        html.recipe = data[i];
        return html.evaluate()
      }
    }
  }
  html.recipe = data;
  return html.evaluate();
}

function getValues() {
  // Paste your Sheet ID here
  const sheetId = '-SHEET ID-';
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
  const rawData = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 2, ss.getLastRow() - 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let data = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
    let tempData = []
    for (let o = 0; o < rawData[i].length; o++) {
      if (rawData[i][o] != '' && rawData[i].length) {
        tempData.push(rawData[i][o]);
      }

    }
    data.push(tempData);
  }
  return data
}



How to get SHEET ID
Sample Image from Web.


In your Index and Recipe HTML's paste this code
index.html


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cz">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Kuchařka ztracených receptů</title>
  <script>
    function getRecipe(title){
      const loc = <?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()?>+`?page=recipe&title=${title}`;
      window.open(loc);
      }
  </script>
</head>
<style>
  button {
    color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
    background-color: rgb(53, 104, 139);
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15pt;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 15px;
    /*15px mezera z top, right, bottom, left*/
  }

  h1 {
    color: rgb(21, 42, 55);
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30pt;
  }

  .button-container {
    text-align: center;
    /*centrování tlačítek*/
    margin-top: 20px;
    /* místo nad tlačítky */
  }
</style>
<body style="background-color:rgb(179, 199, 213);">
  <h1>Kuchařka ztracených receptů</h1>
  <div class="button-container">

    <? for (let i = 0; i < recipe.length; i++) { ?>
    <button onclick="getRecipe(<?= recipe[i][1] ?>)"><?= recipe[i][1] ?></button>
    <? } ?>
  </div>
</body>
</html>



recipe.html


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cz">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Recipe</title>
  <script>
    function winClose(){
      window.top.close();
    }
  </script>
</head>
<style>
  button {
    color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
    background-color: rgb(42, 84, 111);
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }
  h3 {
    color: rgb(21, 42, 55);
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20pt;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <h4 class="title">
    <?= recipe[0] ?>
  </h4>
  <h5>
    <?= recipe[1] ?>
  </h5>
  <p>Ingredients</p>
  <ul>
    <? for(let i = 2; i < recipe.length - 1; i++ ){ ?>
    <li>
      <?= recipe[i] ?>
    </li>
    <? } ?>
  </ul>
  <br>
  Steps:
  <? const lastRecipe = recipe.length - 1; ?>
  <?= recipe[recipe.length - 1] ?>
  <br><br>
  <button onclick="winClose()">Hlavní stránka</button>
</body>
</html>




How to Setup a Web App
Follow these Instruction

If you deploy a new Web App -  How to Setup a Web App

If you're testing the Web App so that you don't have to click new Deployments. - Web Apps



Reference:

App Script Documentation


THANK YOU SOO MUCH!!! i was really lost with the data, im really glad someone helped me.
